# Getting 503 error on some endpoints after restarting heroku server (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, request-timed-out

I am stuck in wired situation. I deployed my code around 7-8 days ago on heroku. The application was working fine and all micro services were working fine. But on Monday night server was taking too much memory so after some time i restart my server. After restarting server most of my micro services start working but still some of my micro services throwing H12 error, I checked the db connectivity and my query on server console which is providing result in reasonable time. But on server it's generating 503 error.

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/v1/search_patients/" host=backend-augmentcare.herokuapp.com request_id=1766d6f2-ae67-43ec-bd16-aada5b5d1008 fwd="39.59.82.36, 172.69.39.6,34.226.147.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://backend-augmentcare.herokuapp.com/api/v1/search_patients/

> {"success":false,"status":404,"errors":["Route Not Found"]}

What does the logs from your app `backend-augmentcare` say? What's the actual source code to the project?

Comment: this url need authentication and other required headers. and the logs from my app backend-augmentcare saying your query taking too much time too load data. but everything was working 2-3 days back. before restarting server query taking 5-7 seconds to load data but after restarting server the same code taking 40- 50 seconds to load data.

Comment: HTTP 404 is not found. If it requires certain headers it should say HTTP 401 Unauthorized. Don't describe what you see. Post the entire logs. Your new edited one has some valuable logs cut off. You still have not shown any source code.